# Удаление обработчика событий

Tags: javascript, события

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли способ удалить обработчик события с анонимной функцией на нативном JS.
Пример кода:

P.S. `buttons` = алфавит с русскими буквами т.е. `buttons.length = 33`,

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".game__alphabet button");    

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Hello, world")
});
```

P.S(2) Есть полный код, но не думаю что он понадобится.

Comment: Что бы удалить обработчик, вам нужна ссылка на эту него. Способа удалить сразу все обработчики конкретного события, вроде как и нет

Comment: Для удаления нужно передать именно ту функцию-обработчик которая была назначена,  почитайте [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events) более подробно

Comment: @ThisMan У меня там еще один цикл который по всем кнопкам пробегает, я знаю что вроде можно удалить с функцией у которой есть имя, но с анонимной не знаю.

Comment: поместите обработчик в переменную, тогда у вас будет ссылка на эту функцию и через нее сможете удалять

Comment: @ThisMan проще поименовать тогда уж

Comment: @ThisMan Я не совсем понял, а как поместить в переменную.

Comment: _а как поместить в переменную_
`const foo = function () {}`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME внутри клика саму себя отвязать можно. вы внутри функции, указатель на нее имеется. эвент-таргет тоже под рукой. так что ифы не нужны

Comment: @ThisMan Я сглупил, я так уже думал делать но забыл как работает this из-за этого думал что так не будет работать функция, но this же ссылается на объект а не на функцию, а я подумал по другому.

Comment: Всем спасибо, может есть способ и лучше реализовать, но у меня все работает. Из-за невнимательности пришлось задать этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне нужно было сделать так чтобы при повторном вызове не вешалось более 1-ого обработчика на 1-ну кнопку, я нашел по моему отличный вариант: я заменил `el.addEventListener("event", func)` на `el.onclick = func` - этот вариант подошел, так как при повторном вызове он не вещает еще один обработчик а перезаписывает его.